# get a URL as variable and display different div dipending on the URL

Tags: asp.net, innerhtml

Is possible to get a URL as variable and display different div (in the same page) based on the value of the variable (URL). More in the details: if I have a page with a webform/popup(DIV), I want to change the innerhtml of this DIV, based on the response I get from the server.

Comment: You could use different parameter in URL

Comment: What i ment was:  if I get a response back a URL1 i show "div1", if if I get a response back a URL2 i show "div2" .  Exemple: i have a div with 2 button that send 2 different request the server will answer me back with a URL with different KEY VALUE

Comment: Using Ajax You can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to create those diffs and use css to set the visibility to false as a default behavior.

In the Ajax success-callback you could overwrite, depending on the response, the visibility off one div-container.

The code will obviously depend on what framework you use on the client (jQuery, plain JS, Angular).